# database design two tables vs join table, which is better

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, hibernate, database-design

I have two tables `matches` and `tournaments` with below structure,

```
MATCH
    MATCH_ID
    PLAYER_ID_1
    PLAYER_ID_2
    RESULT
    TOURNAMENT_ID
```

and

```
TOURNAMENT
    TOURNAMENT_ID
    NAME
    OTHER_DETAILS
```

with one tournament will have multiple matches

and a match may or may not have tournament id

use Cases:

- retrieve all matches
- retrieve all matches by tournaments

Is it good to have `tournament id` in `match` table? Or should I create a separate joining table for `tournament` and `match` mapping?  Which will have good performance when the volume increases?

Comment: This question is opinion-based which is off topic here, consider adding more information are you asking for performance / storage optimisation  or just a better relational model ?

Comment: As @RaymondNijland said, this treads into opinion based territory; but my general thinking is that since a match is not dependent on a tournament for it's existence; a linking table would be more appropriate.

Comment: I think that linking tables without  more columns are useless and use resources . When you join them Tournaents will be NULL and you have to check for NULL in your queries.Values.

Comment: @Uueerdo - do you implement all your optional foreign keys as separate tables?

Comment: @APC no, it's just a general idea, rather than a rule; in the end it really depends on what "feels" better in the particular situation. _and I haven't done an formal survey, but it feels to me that most cases where such a relationship is optional, there usually isn't the possibility of the mistaken assumption of parentage or ownership._ Also, I think it feels in this particular case that the link between the match and tournament might end up with additional attributes, such as who judged it for the tournament, how it was ranked, etc...

Comment: @RaymondNijland what is your experience about MySQL's handling of `NULL`. is it recommended to have a sparse column with majority `NULL` values ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya storing NULL In innoDB does not cost anny (extra) storage at all  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-field-contents.html ... Yes MySQL innoDB has to do a little extra processing to store and finding `NULL` then but CPUs nowadays are so powerfull you don't notice a difference.. Disk I/O is stiil the most critical path in a RDMS preformance wise where HDD are ~100000 times slower then RAM and SSD ~1000 times slower then the RAM

Comment: ... also @MadhurBhaiya innoDB buffer pool can also store more because of above meaning more valueable data as more can fit in the buffers ..  Also [indexing NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html) should work just like anny NOT NULL value yes the costs based calculations in the optimizer also offcource apply here ..   So i disagree with your statement to avoid `NULL` in MySQL atleast for innoDB engine :-)..

Comment: @RaymondNijland my argument for avoiding `NULL` values was based on a book [High Performance MySQL](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/) by people behind Percona. Check this screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/IxcnIA2.png  ; although you are right about InnoDB. Now coming to another question: let's say I have a large InnoDB table with a sparse column having mostly `NULL` values. What would recommend then ? A linking table OR the current setup is fine.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya keep in mind that book is based on the MySQL 5.5 version, the optimizer has much improved by then also InnoDB is a very complex engine so it's hard to "guess"

Answer (score 3):

TOURNAMENT_ID has a 1:M relationship to MATCH. It seems to be a straightforward foreign key. The standard way of implementing foreign keys - even optional foreign keys - is a column on the child table with a foreign key constraint. This would support both your use cases.

A separate table would normally be a head scratcher. I say "normally" because there are schools of thought which abominate NULL columns in databases; either for practical reasons - NULLs can do weird things to our code and need wrangling -  and academic reasons - NULL is contrary to Relational Algebra. So, if you have a data model which forbids the use of nulls you will need a TOURNAMENT_MATCH table to hold Matches which are part of a Tournament. It also would be likely to perform slightly worse than a foreign key column on MATCH, but unless you have a vast amount of data you won't notice the difference.

There is a use case for join tables (also known as junction or intersection tables) and that is implementing many-to-many relationships. Suppose we add a third table to the mix, PLAYER. A Player can participate in many Tournaments and a Tournament has many Players. Classic M:N relationship. So we can resolve it with a join table REGISTERED_PLAYER. which as a compound key of (TOURNAMENT_ID,PLAYER_ID) and the appropriate foreign keys to TOURNAMENT and PLAYER.

---

For the sake of completeness I will mention Link tables from Data Vault modelling. This is an *interesting* modelling technique for Data Warehouses, where - gross simplification alert - tables are defined as Hubs (business and technical keys) and Satellites (immutable attribute records). This approach allows for the capture of data changes over time. Foreign key relationships between Hubs are implemented through Link tables, to support changing relationships over time.

There are several benefits to Data Vault for wrangling large amounts of data in a time-sensitive fashion but an easy-to-understand physical data model isn't one of them. Anyway, [find out more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling).

Answer (score 1):

**The simple rule:** for one-to-many mapping always prefer a foreign key association to a join table association.

It is hard to control a join table using a standard `@OneToMany` Hibernate mapping — you can't just delete rows from a join table, or add an additional row. You will need to use list on the `Tournament` side to do things like that. Another option is to use an additional entity for a join table.

**Note:** `Match` can has a tournaments list too, but looks like `Tournament` is the owner of the association.

Answer (score 0):

A few opinions have been offered in other answers, here is mine.

You do NOT want a separate join table, you would only need that if a Match can be in multiple Tournaments. In your example, just use a foreign key.

The only other suggestion is that if the Match is not part of a Tournament then it is not actually "unknown" which is the meaning of NULL, it is actually something else like "Individual Match". So consider adding a row to your Tournament table, maybe using a known key like 0 or -1, and using that for matches that are not part of a tournament.